# Usage of the word "model"

Tags: definition, model-theory

In science we usually say some concept on paper is a "model" of some real-life concept. For example the Bohr model of the atom describes how real-world atoms behave in a particular context or situation and we use that model when we find it useful. So the Bohr model is a "model" of the atom.

But in mathematics it seems to be the other way around? A real life-concept being a "model" of some mathematical concept on paper? For example the natural numbers being a model for the Peano axioms.

Why is it "backwards" like this? Why can't we say the Peano axioms are a model of the natural numbers, or ZFC is a model of some real-life concept we call a "set" and so on?

Comment: It's just terminology. A set of axioms like PA or ZFC, is rather called a 'theory' in first order logic.

Comment: As with all terminology, use of these words and phrases becomes conventional through historical literature.  Note the distinction between a *conceptual* model of a real world phenomenon and a *valid* model of an axiomatic theory.  Applied mathematics will treat both senses of the word *model*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use the term 'models' to interpret the double turnstile symbol?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860309/why-use-the-term-models-to-interpret-the-double-turnstile-symbol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I don't think it's backwards at all.

The intuition that worked for me is that **a model of a theory is an example of how that theory can work**. In real life, a model of some object is usually a *simpler* thing satisfying the same *basic* properties as that object. The mathematical analogue is the idea of a model of the theory of a structure: each structure $\mathcal{A}$ has an associated set of sentences $Th(\mathcal{A})$, its *theory*, and we could (we don't, but we could) say that a "model of $\mathcal{A}$" is a model of $Th(\mathcal{A})$ in the usual sense.

This is **not** a trivial notion: for almost every $\mathcal{A}$ (specifically: exactly when $\mathcal{A}$ is infinite) there are lots of structures not isomorphic to $\mathcal{A}$ but which are models of $Th(\mathcal{A})$. And indeed we often have situations where $\mathcal{A}$ is complicated but $Th(\mathcal{A})$ has simple models.

So I'd say that the real conceptual shift is realizing that when we speak of (say) "the Bohr model of the atom," we have in the back of our minds some "basic properties" of atoms which we're trying to capture. Making these explicit we see a two step process:

- Decide what the basic properties of atoms that we care about are.
- Build stuff satisfying those properties.

We then think of the actual model-building process as that second step, with the first step being something much more fundamental and complicated.

Comment: I read this answer several times but I still don't understand how it isn't backwards. The Bohr model is the simpler version of the real-life atom. The Peano axioms are the simpler version of the real-life natural numbers. So then why aren't the axioms the "model" here?

Comment: @user709833 What does it mean to be a "version" of something? It means you share a bunch of properties with it. That set of properties are the *theory* which the Bohr model satisfies. The idea is that it's a two-step process (as per my answer): before you can say that the Bohr model is satisfactory, you need to specify what properties of the atom you care about.

Comment: Looking at PA, the analogy is: $\mathbb{N}$ is the actual atom, PA is the set of properties of atoms we care about, and [a nonstandard model of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic) is the Bohr model. The structure $\mathbb{N}$ is also a model of PA, identically to how the actual atom is a model of all the basic properties atoms satisfy.

Comment: @user709833 But of course, at the end of the day it's just terminology. Intuition is subjective; at the end of the day, just accept that the intuition behind the introduction of the vocabulary was different, and that for good or ill that's what the term means in this field. (This happens all the time: [rings aren't circular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) and [mice aren't furry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_(set_theory)))

Comment: But then does it make sense to say that the real-life atom is a model of these "shared properties" between the atom and Bohr model?

Comment: @user709833 Sure - the atom is a great model of the atom! Granted, that's really silly, but according to this stance it's totally legit. The mathematical usage throws away the requirement that the model be simpler than the "intended structure" (or even that an intended structure exist in the first place) in favor of just demanding similar behavior in a technical sense. One argument for doing this is that "simpler" is hiding a lot of conceptual detail, and dropping it yields a clearer and still interesting and important notion.

Comment: What about saying the real-life atom is a model of the Bohr model? (just switching the order). I am still struggling to understand what "model" even means now lol

Comment: @user709833 We could do that too. The point is that we've abstracted from "the Bohr model of the atom" to "the Bohr model, which shares [basic properties] with the atom" to the idea of organizing/comparing structures in terms of their basic properties - so that the Bohr model of the atom and the actual atom each fall into the category of "models of [basic properties]." That shift may sound like it gives up something fundamental, namely the idea of "intended structure," but it turns out to be incredibly fruitful.

Comment: For that matter, once you go far enough in logic you'll see that theories themselves are incredibly interesting objects! A structure $\mathcal{A}$ satisfying a set of sentences $T$ can be thought of as a "concrete instance" of $T$, and even when what we actually care about is $T$ these $\mathcal{A}$s are worth studying and are often easier to handle. Which further blurs the idea of "intended object," and motivates as fundamental the notion of a structure satisfying some sentences.

Comment: How are you using the word "theory" or "satisfies"?

Comment: @user709833 In the technical sense in logic. A theory is a set of first-order sentences (unless we're working in some other logic), and satisfaction is [defined by Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Evaluation_of_truth_values) - intuitively, "$\mathcal{A}$ satisfies $T$" (or "$\mathcal{A}$ models $T$" - latex code "\models") means "all the sentences in $T$ are true in $\mathcal{A}$".

Comment: And to reiterate, I **really** wouldn't overthink this. If what I've said isn't useful, just accept that it's a weird usage and learn how it works. Over time it will become more intuitive, but trying to get a totally satisfying explanation *first* is likely to not work.

Comment: I don't have much choice but to overthink when I don't understand something. :( Are the Peano axioms also the "theory" or are they the "first order sentences" of some other theory? (or I guess, second order in the case of induction? second order theory?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99319/discussion-between-noah-schweber-and-user709833).